# Prove the following estimate in the complex plane

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

I'm stuck in the proof of the following inequality for $|z|$ large enough:
$$
\left\vert \frac{z}{\sqrt{z^{2}+a}}\sinh (\sqrt{z^{2}+a})-\sinh
(z)\right\vert \leq C\left\vert \sqrt{z^{2}+a}-z\right\vert ,
$$

with $\left\vert \mathfrak{Re}(z)\right\vert \leq M$ for some positive $M$
and $a$ is a positive real number.
I have tried to write $z=x+iy$ but this didn't work. I have tried with equivalences and I have got
$$
\left\vert \frac{z}{\sqrt{z^{2}+a}}\sinh (\sqrt{z^{2}+a})-\sinh
(z)\right\vert =O(z^{-1}),
$$
and
$$
\left\vert \sqrt{z^{2}+a}-z\right\vert =O(z^{-1}).
$$
This doesn't allow to conclude.
This is what I have done:
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&\left\vert \frac{z}{\sqrt{z^{2}+a}}\sinh (\sqrt{z^{2}+a})-\sinh
(z)\right\vert  \\
&=&\left\vert \frac{z}{\sqrt{z^{2}+a}}\sinh (\sqrt{z^{2}+a})-\frac{z}{\sqrt{%
z^{2}+a}}\sinh (z)+\frac{z}{\sqrt{z^{2}+a}}\sinh (z)-\sinh (z)\right\vert  \\
&\leq &\left\vert \frac{z}{\sqrt{z^{2}+a}}\right\vert \left\vert \sinh (%
\sqrt{z^{2}+a})-\sinh (z)\right\vert +\left\vert \frac{z}{\sqrt{z^{2}+a}}%
-1\right\vert \left\vert \sinh (z)\right\vert  \\
&\leq &M\left\vert \sqrt{z^{2}+a}-z\right\vert +O(\left\vert z\right\vert
^{-2}).
\end{eqnarray*}

Since $\left\vert \frac{z}{\sqrt{z^{2}+a}}-1\right\vert
=O(\left\vert z\right\vert ^{-1}),$ we get
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left\vert \frac{z}{\sqrt{z^{2}+a}}\sinh (\sqrt{z^{2}+a})-\sinh
(z)\right\vert  &\leq &M\left\vert \sqrt{z^{2}+a}-z\right\vert +M^{\prime
}\left\vert \sqrt{z^{2}+a}-z\right\vert , \\
&=&M^{\prime \prime }\left\vert \sqrt{z^{2}+a}-z\right\vert .
\end{eqnarray*}
Des this seem correct?. Any other ideas?.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Didn't you post this same question a day ago? Please do not remove posts and repost.

Comment: How do you define which branch of the square root is chosen?

Comment: @Martin R, Does that make a difference in the computations?.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin  Sorry sir, thank you for the response.

Comment: Unless I am completely mistaken, it *does* make a difference for the term on the right-hand side.

Comment: Thank you sir for the answer. Would you please explain more?. If I'm not mistaken you have meant by the branches these two quantities $\sqrt{z^{2}}=\pm z$?.

Comment: *You* want a proof of that inequality, so *you* should be able to tell us what $\sqrt{z^2+a}$ stands for.

Comment: @MartinR $$\sqrt{z^{2}+a}=ze^{\frac{1}{2}\log (1+\frac{a}{z^{2}})}=z\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{z^{2}},} $$

for any $1+\frac{a}{z^{2}}\notin (-\infty ,0]$ (The principal branch cut for 
$\log $)$.$ That means that $\Im (z)$ $\notin \lbrack -ai,ai].$ So, for
large enough $|z|$ every thing is well defined.